# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info; update setuptools doesn't work

Tags: egg, info

I'm trying to install a private python module with command: "pip install . -i "private url" "

I had this error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-rnoryb6e\

I uninstall Python 38 and reinstall it.
Pip is updated and setup_tools is also updated.

And now I have this error:

> D:\L1\onelib\trx-5g>D:\L1\onelib\venv\Scripts\pip.exe install . -i https://artifactory-espoo1.***********.com/artifactory/api/pypi/ulphy-pypi-prod-virtual/simple
> Looking in indexes:
> https://artifactory-espoo1.***********.com/artifactory/api/pypi/ulphy-pypi-prod-virtual/simple,
> https://artifactory-espoo2.***********.com/artifactory/ap
> i/pypi/mn-l1-pz-int-lib-local/simple Processing d:\l1\onelib\trx-5g
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'd:\l1\onelib\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_4yae_lz\se
> tup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_4yae_lz\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().repla ce('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> egg_info --egg-base
> 'C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-zvlq1hsf'
> cwd: C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_4yae_lz
> Complete output (15 lines):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_4yae_lz\setup.py",
> line 23, in 
> version=os.environ.get('CI_COMMIT_TAG', f'0.0.0+{get_local_version_label()}'),
> File "C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_4yae_lz\setup.py",
> line 17, in get_local_version_label
> commit_hash = subprocess.check_output(COMMAND.split()).decode('utf-8').strip()
> File "C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 411, in check_output
> return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
> File "C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 489, in run
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
> File "C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 854, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 1307, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
> full command output.

Where the logs are located ?

- I'm on Windows 10.
- Python 3.8.5.

I launched this command via Pycharm and via cmd windows and same result.

I tried to run the command in administration mode; and same result.

I have tried every solution available on stackoverflow and nothing solves my error.

I tried to find C:\Users\hwi_pi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_4yae_lz\setup.py to see the file setup.py but foled pip-req-build-_4yae_lz doesn't exist.

I can access to https://artifactory-espoo1.************.com/artifactory/api/pypi/ulphy-pypi-prod-virtual/simple via firefox; but I can't download it in .zip for example

Someone to help please ?